# discord.py не получается отобразить в консоли member.name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

хочу чтобы когда пользователь писал команду "наградить" ему писало в чат: " вы не имеете доступ к этой команде " я это уже сделал, и теперь мне нужно чтобы в консоли писало member.name (ник) но выходит ошибка: name "Member" has not atribute "message".
вот команда:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        print(f"User: {str(member.name)} хотел использовать команду: наградить")
        await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(
            description=f'Доступ закрыт!', color=disnake.Color.red()))
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: А откуда вы здесь берете объект `member`? Вы пытаетесь его использовать в `member.name`, но самого объекта `member` нигде нет, поэтому интерпретатор не знает что делать.

Comment: А нужно добавлять member в ```async def on_command_error(ctx, error, member)```?

Comment: `discord-py` передает в качестве аргументов `on_command_error()` только контекст `ctx` и исключение `exception` (`error`). Отдельно объект участника сервера передавать незачем. Вы можете получить его из контекста как автора команды

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно получить member из ctx.author, вот как это можно сделать:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        print(f"User: {str(ctx.author.name)} хотел использовать команду: наградить") # используйте ctx.author вместо member
        await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(
            description=f'Доступ закрыт!', color=disnake.Color.red()))
    else:
        raise error
```